# Android google maps huge lag when adding colored markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I noticed a huge amount of lag when adding some (50) colored markers onto a google map. There are about 20 different hue colors the markers need to have. I tried storing the generated `BitmapDescriptor` in a hashmap and from a background thread and retrieving it when adding the marker, which decreased the lag by about 10%. When I set no marker color and leave it on the default red, I get no lag at all.

How I add the markers:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(snippet)
                    .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hue)));
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent some of this lag, except using clustering, which will not work for me in this case.

Comment: When do you add these markers? Can you provide some more code?

Comment: I add them in the `onPostExecute()` method of my AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issu, see [#7174](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7174) for more informations.

To avoid this problem, you can use this directly (all the markers will be red in this case):

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker()
```

Or the easiest way, use a custom markers :

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker)
```

Comment: This issue should be fixed as stated in the bugreport, but it seems it isn't. Is there any way to get the default maps marker image to use as resource?

Comment: I don't know, but this could be a very useful link :
https://mapicons.mapsmarker.com/